# XCode: unknown class in interface builder file when using static library

Tags: swift, storyboard, interface-builder, xcode7, static-libraries

I am currently working on an iPad app with the following environment:

- XCode 7
- iOS 9.2
- Swift 2
- Storyboard
- List item

My project contains a static library (myLib.a) that has been created by someone else. This lib contains a bunch of classes and has been written in Objective-C.
I have imported the lib (myLib.a) as well as all the headers (.h files) in my Swift project.

The library contains a class that is a subclass of UITextField and is called CustomUITextField. My project contains the file CustomUITextField.h. This class applies a specific layout to a UITextField.

The library contains as well a UIViewController called LoginViewController. My project contains the file LoginViewController.h.

In my storyboard, I have designed a UIViewController and changed the class to LoginViewController. I then added a UITextField and changed it to CustomUITextField.

When I launch my app, the CustomUITextField is rendered as a UITextField and I have the error message:

```
Unknown class CustomUITextField in interface builder file
```

When I look at both LoginViewController and CustomUITextField in my Storyboard, it doesn't allow me to add the Module Name. Even if I force it, I still have the same issue.

Of course, if I create my own LoginViewController and CustomUITextField (in Swift or Objective-C), everything is working fine. So, I suppose there is something wrong with the library... Is there a specific configuration or flag to use somewhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself.

I just had to create a main.swift file and force my app to load my custom class.

```
import UIKit

//My custom class
CustomUITextField.self

UIApplicationMain(Process.argc, Process.unsafeArgv, NSStringFromClass(UIApplication), NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate))
```

Comment: *coughs uncontrollably* Why?.. Are they lazily loaded? Experiencing this same issue right now.

Comment: Your solution is confirmed to not to be working for me